# Fetch XML data from Plex Media Server

Tags: php, xml

I want to get information from Plex Media Server trough `foreach`. I have succeeded fetching the content from an URL but I can't get the information I want to print out on the page.

This is the var_dump from the URL:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'size' => string '349' (length=3)
      'mediaTagPrefix' => string '/system/bundle/media/flags/' (length=27)
      'mediaTagVersion' => string '1322272914' (length=10)
      'sortAsc' => string '1' (length=1)
      'viewGroup' => string 'movie' (length=5)
      'viewMode' => string '458803' (length=6)
      'art' => string '/:/resources/movie-fanart.jpg' (length=29)
      'title1' => string 'Filmer' (length=6)
      'identifier' => string 'com.plexapp.plugins.library' (length=27)
  public 'Video' => 
    array
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array
              ...
          public 'Media' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[351]
              ...
          public 'Genre' => 
            array
              ...
          public 'Writer' => 
            array
              ...
          public 'Director' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[356]
              ...
          public 'Country' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[357]
              ...
          public 'Role' => 
            array
              ...
  1 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array
          ...
      public 'Media' => 

And so on...
```

This is the print_r data from the URL:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [size] => 349 [mediaTagPrefix] => /system/bundle/media/flags/ [mediaTagVersion] => 1322272914 [sortAsc] => 1 [viewGroup] => movie [viewMode] => 458803 [art] => /:/resources/movie-fanart.jpg [title1] => Filmer [identifier] => com.plexapp.plugins.library ) [Video] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [ratingKey] => 2663 [key] => /library/metadata/2663 [studio] => Touchstone Pictures [type] => movie [title] => 10 Things I Hate About You [contentRating] => PG-13 [summary] => "10 Things I Hate About You" Ã¤r en amerikansk lÃ¥ngfilm frÃ¥n 1999 i regi av Gil Junger. NÃ¤r Cameron bÃ¶rjar high school fÃ¶rÃ¤lskar han sig snabbt i den sÃ¶ta Bianca. Han hjÃ¤lper henne med hemlÃ¤xorna i franska fÃ¶r att fÃ¥ henne att bli intresserad av honom. NÃ¤r han ber att fÃ¥ gÃ¥ pÃ¥ skolbalen med henne fÃ¥r han dock veta att hennes pappa har bestÃ¤mt att hon inte fÃ¥r gÃ¥ pÃ¥ dejt sÃ¥ lÃ¤nge Biancas syster Kat Ã¤r singel. Kat Ã¤r stÃ¤ndigt pÃ¥ dÃ¥ligt humÃ¶r och ovÃ¤nlig och definitivt inte nÃ¥gon man vill gÃ¥ pÃ¥ dejt med. Cameron mÃ¥ste ocksÃ¥ konkurrera om Biancas gunst med snyggingen Joey. Cameron kommer dÃ¥ pÃ¥ en plan: att be Pat, som enligt ryktet har sÃ¥lt sin lever fÃ¶r att kÃ¶pa hÃ¶gtalare, att gÃ¥ med Kat pÃ¥ skolbalen mot betalning. [rating] => 7 [year] => 1999 [thumb] => /library/metadata/2663/thumb?t=1328119876 [art] => /library/metadata/2663/art?t=1328119876 [duration] => 5940000 [originallyAvailableAt] => 1999-03-31 [addedAt] => 1328119758 [updatedAt] => 1328119876 ) [Media] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 2614 [duration] => 5611000 [bitrate] => 1021 [width] => 544 [height] => 304 [aspectRatio] => 1.78 [audioChannels] => 2 [audioCodec] => mp3 [videoCodec] => mpeg4 [videoResolution] => sd [container] => avi [videoFrameRate] => PAL [optimizedForStreaming] => 0 ) [Part] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [key] => /library/parts/2628/file.avi [duration] => 5611000 [file] => G:\Movies\10 things that I hate about you (1999)\10 things that I hate about you (1999).avi [size] => 733679616 ) ) ) [Genre] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [tag] => Coming of age ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [tag] => Komedi ) ) ) [Writer] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [tag] => Karen McCullah Lutz ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [tag] => Kirsten Smith ) ) ) [Director] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [tag] => Gil Junger ) ) [Country] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [tag] => USA ) ) [Role] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [tag] => Allison Janney ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [tag] => Larry Miller ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] =>
```

This is the code I have right now:

```
$url = 'http://localhost:32400/library/sections/12/all';
$achxml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($achxml->attributes AS $ach) {
    echo $ach->Video['title'].'<br>';
}
```

The only thing I getting out of this is... well - nothing! It doesn't print out anything at all! So I'm asking you now, what's wrong with my `foreach`? You can read more about PlexNine or what they now calling it, here: http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/PlexNine_AdvancedInfo

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working now! Here's the solution:

```
foreach($achxml->Video AS $child) {
    echo $child['title'];
}
```